# Convert from CanvasBitmap to ID3D11Texture2D

Tags: c++

I have a program that prepares a movie frame using Win2d. The frame is in CanvasBitmap format.
I would like to save such frames as a movie. For this, I'm switching from CanvasBitmap to ID3D11Texture2D. I do it as below, but after saving dozens of samples, I have errors of the type 'Device lost'. Probably the reason is the release of the sample.
Is there another way to switch from CanvasBitmap to ID3D11Texture2D - so that saving the movie frames efficiently?

```
int AddWin2DFrame (CanvasBitmap^ frame) 
{
    ComPtr<ID2D1Device> nativeDevice = GetWrappedResource<ID2D1Device>(frame->Device);
    ComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap1> nativeBitmap = GetWrappedResource<ID2D1Bitmap1>(frame);

    ComPtr<IDXGISurface> dxgiSurface;
    CHK(nativeBitmap->GetSurface(&dxgiSurface));
    ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> d3dResource;
    CHK(dxgiSurface.As(&d3dResource));

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> writeBuffer;
    CHK(MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), d3dResource.Get(), 0, false, &writeBuffer));

    ComPtr<IMF2DBuffer> p2DBuffer;
    DWORD length;
    writeBuffer->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMF2DBuffer), &p2DBuffer);
    CHK(p2DBuffer->GetContiguousLength(&length));
    CHK(writeBuffer->SetCurrentLength(length));

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IMFSample> writeSample;

    CHK(MFCreateSample(&writeSample));

    CHK(writeSample->AddBuffer(writeBuffer.Get()));

    CHK(writeSample->SetSampleDuration(sampleDuration));
    CHK(writeSample->SetSampleTime(_hnsSampleTime));

    CHK(_spSinkWriter->WriteSample(_streamIndex, writeSample.Get()));
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try doing it other way around - prepare frame using DirectX texture and then create `CanvasBitmap` from it using `CreateFromDirect3D11Surface`

Comment: It does not make sense. Movie frame write buffer expects 3d texture: MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer.
I have a bitmap in CanvasBitmap format (ID2D1Bitmap1) and want to save it to a movie with hardware support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has already been solved. It is fixed by setting MF_SINK_WRITER_D3D_MANAGER as below:

```
ComPtr<IMFAttributes> spAttr;
CHK(MFCreateAttributes(&spAttr, 4));
CHK(spAttr->SetUnknown(MF_SINK_WRITER_D3D_MANAGER, deviceManager.Get()));
.........
CHK(MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(ws1.c_str(), spByteStream.Get(), spAttr.Get(), &_spSinkWriter));
```